# Prompting to save on comboBox value change

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have a datagridview and a combobox in my winform.  The gridview data changes based on what's selected in the combobox.  Data can be inserted and deleted (by checking the comboboxcolumn ) in the grid to the database.  If a user wants to add/delete data and forgets to hit save, I want to prompt the user if they want to save or not.  My save function saves if changes have been made.

***Here's what I've tried:***

```
 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     var result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save your changes?", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
            {

                Save(false);
            }
}
```

However, doing this will prompt the user when the form loads up.  (Since there's a default value in the combobox)

```
 private void comboBox1_SelectionChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save your changes?", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
            {

                Save(false);
            }

        }
```

Using this event will prompt me when I change the value in the combobox, but instead of saving on the form that I want to leave, it saves the grid data on the form I'm going to and leaves the previous grid data unchanged.  I want to save changes on the grid that I'm leaving.

Do I need to keep track of comboBox changes somehow and save on the previous one, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of a boolean flag value to indicate that your form has already been loaded and prevent your code in the event handler from running before that:

```
private bool _loaded = false;
```

I usually flip the boolean flag within a `HandleCreated` event handler.

```
void MainForm_HandleCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _loaded = true;
}
```

Wire it up on load:

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HandleCreated += MainForm_HandleCreated;
}
```

Then you can change your combo box handler to this:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(_loaded)
    {
        var result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save your changes?", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
        {

            Save(false);
        }
    }
}
```

The reason I use the `HandleCreated` event handler rather than the `Load` event handler itself to flip the flag is because your combobox events can fire after the `Load` event causing the behavior you've observed, and the `HandleCreated` event will only fire right when the form is being displayed for the first time.

Comment: Could you provide an example of this please?

Comment: Bear with me, I'm working one up.  I'm on the train so it's a little slow.

Comment: No worries, just curious of how you would do it as I often also come across this

Comment: Hmm...not working.  When the form loads, I added a few records under the first comboBox value, then I switched over to another without clicking save and it didn't prompt me.

Comment: @roryap Any other suggestions?  (Refer to my comment above)

Comment: @JoshM -- Can you add some break points and test it?  Is it actually hitting your HandleCreated event handler?  What about when it hits your combo box event handler?  What is the value of the boolean?

Comment: @roryap I put a breakpoint in my load, eventhandler, and combobox event.  The handlecreated doesn't get reached.  When the combobox event is reached , the bool value is false;